# Move space to different display

Tags: display, spaces

How do I move an entire space to a different window?

Simply grabbing seems not to work.

**EDIT:**

In mission control I have `Displays have separate Spaces` ticked.

When opening mission control (swipe with three fingers upwards) It shows the different Desktops (labeled `Desktop 1` to `Desktop n`).

Let's say I have two Monitors, one external and the mac screen, the Desktops (Spaces) are distributed as follows:

- mac: `Desktop 1`, `Desktop 2`, `Desktop 3`
- external: `Desktop 4`, `Desktop 5`

What I want to do is e.g. move `Desktop 4` from external to mac, such that:

- mac: `Desktop 1`, `Desktop 2`, `Desktop 3`, `Desktop 4`
- external: `Desktop 5`

Comment: Do you mean moving an entire window to a different Space?

Comment: What's the status of System Prefs/Mission Control - 'Displays have separate Spaces'? On or off.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I mean moving an entire Space to a different monitor.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have Displays have separate Spaces On.

Comment: OK, I never use it that way - but, afaik, so long as you have more spaces than displays, you just click in the display you want the Space to appear, then call it, by key command or swipe. It will appear on that display.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Can you please clarify? I also edit my question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: This is probably easier if you enable the key commands… go to Sys Prefs>Keyboard>Shortcuts>Mission Control. Enable the default commands for 'Switch to Desktop *n*'. Then you should be able to directly call any Space to your currently active display that way. [I'm not used to separate spaces, I keep mine in pairs, & don't have anything with a trackpad, so this is a bit of a guess as to exactly how it functions.]

Comment: Also see - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120148/cant-move-spaces-from-one-screen-to-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click Ctrl+Arrow Up, you will see the list of desktops in each monitor. On external, select Desktop 5 as active desktop. Then you click Ctrl+Arrow Up again and drag to move the desktop 4 on external monitor to MacBook monitor.

Comment: Note: You can cannot drag to move the active desktop you are on. Say you stand on Desktop 4 (external) and Ctrl+Arrow Up to drag Desktop 4 to MacBook monitor. This will not work as it is active on external monitor.

Comment: Thanks, not sure though why this didn't work when I tried it... Anyways it works now...